# How to use a partial in a rails nested routing simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-routes

I have a nested route specifically around properties and downtowns. Downtowns have many properties.

The problem i'm having is that the edit form ended up getting quite large and I really would like to split it up in to a few partials for ease.

I've basically tried something similar to this here.

```
= simple_form_for([@downtown, @property]) do |f|
  = render partial: "/properties/partial_test", locals: {resource: f }
```

The error I get when I do this is

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Properties#edit

Missing partial properties/_partial_test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}
```

Right now all I have in the partial is filler text, but reading the error messaging, I'm assuming that the error is around how i'm trying to render the actual partial in my `locals`.

Would anyone have any thoughts or ideas on how to get this to work here?

Much thanks in advance! (also happy to share more code like my routes file or controller)

Comment: There should be `app/views/properties/_partial_test.html.erb` (.haml). Do you have the file there?

Comment: there is. Right now i just have filler text in it, but i do have one.

Comment: Can you also include the edit action of the controller?